# Processing JSON array with java

Tags: java, json

I have following list.

```
  [{
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T11:02:21.847",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-29",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T11:02:21.847",
    "tpr": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-28",
    "tim": "2017-01-20T12:01:08.358",
    "tpr": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-20T12:01:08.358",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-20T17:35:17.495",
    "tpr": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:04:44.586",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:15:46.051",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  }]
```

I am going to create a multi series line chart from above data set. X axis becomes **tim** values. Y axis becomes **tpr**. Lines should be group by **frd**. So I am trying to get a new `json` which is needed to draw the chart from above data.

I am trying following to get distinct tim values.

```
 Set<String> tims = new HashSet<String>();

    for (Record record : array) {
        tims.add(record.getTim());
    }

    List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(tims);
    Collections.sort(sorted);
```

Then can I get all the frd values with relevant tpr values for each distinct tim?

My final output should look like:

```
[
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-19T11:02:21.847",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": 2408.5,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-20T12:01:08.358",
    "2017-06-28": 2408.5,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-20T17:35:17.495",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:04:44.586",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:15:46.051",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  }
]
```

**Edited**

I have tried following.

```
Set<String> d_tims = new HashSet<String>();

    for (Record record : array) {
        d_tims.add(record.getTim());
    }

    List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(d_tims);
    Collections.sort(sorted);

    List<Map<String, String>> tims = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for (String record : sorted) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("tim", record);
        for (Record record1 : array) {
            if (record.equals(record1.getTim())){
                map.put(record1.getFrd(), record1.getTpr().toString());
            }
        }
        tims.add(map);
    }
```

Then I got the json array as I expected. Please be kind enough to post if there is another way better than this.

Thank you

Comment: Convert to a `List< Map<String, String> >` and for each in the list get the `tim`

Comment: @m_callens Could you please check on **Edited** section. I have tried     List< Map<String, String> > and got json as I expected. Please mention if there is another way to do it better than I used because it may has thousands of data.

Comment: in your sample data: ""2017-06-28": null," if there is no mapping 'tpr', 'null' has to be presented?

Comment: yes if there is no mapping 'tpr', 'null' has be presented. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Java 8 and Stream API, here is code:

```
final Record[] array = N.fromJSON(Record[].class, json); // Provided by open source library: AbacusUtil

// sorted by 'frd' and grouped by 'tim'
final Map<String, List<Record>> groupedByTim = Arrays.stream(array).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::getFrd))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getTim()));
final List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Record>> entry : groupedByTim.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("tim", entry.getKey());

    for (Record r : entry.getValue()) {
        map.put(r.getFrd(), r.getTpr());
    }
    result.add(map);
}

N.println(N.toJSON(result, JSC.create().setPrettyFormat(true))); // Provided by open source library: AbacusUtil
```

Two shorter solutions with pure java 8 Stream API:

```
Arrays.stream(array).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::getFrd))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Record::getTim, e -> {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("tim", e.getTim());
        map.put(e.getFrd(), e.getTpr());
        return map;
    }, (a, b) -> {
        a.putAll(b);
        return a;
    })).values();
```

Or by [AbacusUtil](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil)

```
Stream.of(array).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::getFrd))
        .toMap(Record::getTim, e -> N.asLinkedHashMap("tim", e.getTim(), e.getFrd(), e.getTpr()), 
               (a, b) -> {
                a.putAll(b);
                return a;}).values();
```

And here is the output without null value:

```
[
     {
         "tim":"2017-01-19T10:15:46.051", 
         "2017-06-30":"2276.5"
     }, 
     {
         "tim":"2017-01-20T17:35:17.495", 
         "2017-06-30":"2408.5"
     }, 
     {
         "tim":"2017-01-19T11:02:21.847", 
         "2017-06-29":"2408.5", 
         "2017-06-30":"2276.5"
     }, 
     {
         "tim":"2017-01-19T10:04:44.586", 
         "2017-06-30":"2276.5"
     }, 
     {
         "tim":"2017-01-20T12:01:08.358", 
         "2017-06-28":"2408.5", 
         "2017-06-30":"2276.5"
     }
 ]
```

Comment: What is "N" here?

Comment: An utility class in AbacusUtil